# Some javascript runs and some doesn't

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I'm not sure when exactly this started to happen.  My development environment in C#/VS2013 was looking great with the new code (ajax) that I had been working on.  I went to deploy this code to a beta site and some of the javascript code wasn't working (the tab menu on the one page which is simulated below).

I then went back to my dev environment and saw that it was working in IE just fine but not in firefox or chrome.  In attempting to clean it up I broke it in IE now as well which I guess is a good thing in that I have a way to troubleshoot/verify the issue now.

I created a test page in my project and copied in a tab controller test.

```
@section Scripts
{

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });

    alert("test");


</script>
}

<body>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab2</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        tab 1
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        tab 2
    </div>

</div>
```

The alert() fires when I call the page so I know the javascript is running.  Also, the tab controller creates the tabs at the top of the page but both tab1 and tab2 show and the tabs don't toggle pages.

The menu options which are twitter bootstrap menus also work with no issues.

My layout.cshtml has the following towards the top:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

and this after the renderbody section:  (I've tried playing with the placement of the above section and the rendersection scripts below.)

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

BundleConfig.cs has this:

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        RegisterStyleBundles(bundles);

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate*")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.migrate-121.min.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
            );

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
                "~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));


        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }

    private static void RegisterStyleBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css")
                        .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css")
                        .Include("~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css")
                        .Include("~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

In firebug I'm not seeing any errors other than a list of css issues which all seem to be related to versioning and according to the jquery site they are to be ignored. (they were also there before this whole thing started to happen).

Comment: `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)` try this, cause c# is a case sensitive language

Comment: I tried that and also lower casing the @section scripts {} with the same results...

Comment: inspect in browser and check if scripts are bundled or not, let me know

Comment: Interesting...  I'm seeing this: 

 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script> 

I did update jquery to 2.1.1 then backed it out to 1.11.1 but all three versions are showing... Could this be my issue?  I don't see the other versions listed anywhere...

Comment: Otherwise, yes, it looks like it bundled everything else.

Comment: Holy cow. Thanks, Maulik.  That was absolutely it!  The nuget didn't delete the scripts when it upgraded the javascript versions.  I went into content/scripts and deleted them by hand and went to only 1.11.1 version and it works! Thanks for your insite; I've been struggling with this for days....

Comment: If you've figured it out now, then you can either delete your question or you can provide an answer yourself (and accept it) so finish off this question so it has a resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuget shows that it's removing older versions of jquery from the project but it doesn't actually remove the jquery files.  The answer is to remove the older versions from the scripts folder in the project outsite of visual studio.

Comment: I was thinking more on this; I'm surprised I haven't seen anyone else having this issue and thought I'd do another update.  The older jquery scripts did transfer to my test server and was causing an issue out there is well.  This was 3 days of my life I'll never get back.